# Something said or done that is meant for you to overhear or notice, but isn't directed toward you

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Say you were bullied by someone as a kid, and they see you years later and say or do something in front of you in a way to remind you of the past, without directly doing or saying it to you. (But they know you will overhear it.)

How do we say this?

> They did it in a __________ way

Answer (score 1):

You could use *taunting* as an adjective:

> They did it in a **taunting** way.

According to Oxford:

> **taunt** (*n.*) a remark made in order to anger, wound, or provoke someone

Taunts are often made directly to the person; however, if someone is deliberately saying something to someone else mostly to annoy or provoke you, that could still be described as a "taunt".

Another possibility would be:

> They did it in a **provocative** way.

Again, according to Oxford:

> **provocative** (*adj.*) causing annoyance, anger, or another strong reaction, especially deliberately